# How "switch depended mode" is working under the NIC configuration on Microsoft Windows Server 2012?

Tags: windows, switch-statement, nic

Hello can any one help me to describe the switch depended mode on the Windows Server 2012? Because I'm new on Windows Server platform. Helpful answers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to read this blog.This contains answer to your question.

[MICROSOFT WINDOWS SERVER 2012 NIC TEAMING CONFIGURATION](http://madurad.wordpress.com/2014/03/20/microsoft-windows-server-2012-nic-teaming-configuration/)